Math Geometry Help!
So I think I have solved this question, I would love to just make sure that I did it correctly.
Here is the question. 
So starting off I know that we have to split the shaded and unshaded parts into same sized triangles. I labeled some of the different points to help make it clearer.
After that I drew a parallel line of AC from the point E, and labeled the other end F.
Then I drew a parallel line of BD starting from the point G and labeled it H.
This is what it looks like now:

So with this I know that △AEC = △EFC and therefore the areas are equal because of SSS.
Also with that I know that △GBD = △GDH and also have the same areas because of SSS.
So after that I have to figure out the biggest shaded part and see if I could match two triangles from it. So Starting from the point in between points FH I labeled J and then drew a line parallel to EF going up. Labeling it I.

(I showed the different parallel lines are the same length by the different type of lines on them.)
So now after having all of my lines drawn I can look at each individual triangle. (I just want to say something in the [] means area. so △[EFC] just means the area of triangle EFC)
△[AEC] = △[EFC]
△[GBD] = △[GDH]
△[EIJ] = △[EJF]
△[IGJ] = △[GHJ]
△[GBD] = △[GDH]
So because we have just proven that each shaded and unshaded triangle have the same area, we know that within the whole parallelogram the shaded and unshaded areas are equal!

Alternatively, the area of a triangle is $bh/2$ Since all of these triangles have the same height you just have to show that the sum of their bases are equal.

Let b1 and b2 be the bases of the triangles in white--call those triangles A and B. The area of the parallelogram (call it C) is (b1+b2)h. The area of triangle A is b1h/2 and the area of triangle B is b2*h/2. ie A+B = (1/2)C.

[I should have written area(A)+area(B)=(1/2)Area(C), but didn't want to be overly confusing for you.] Don't forget that 'heights' need to be perpendicular to bases.... The red lines you've drawn are different from 'height.'

What you (Violet) have written is correct though.

The area of a parallagram is the base times the height.  The area of a triangle is half the base times the height.  The sum of the areas of multiple triangles that all have the same height will be have the sum of the bases times the height.  The sum of the areas of multiple triangles whose bases are colinear so as to form the base of a parallelogram will be half the base of the to parallelogram times the height which is half the area of the parallelogram.  So both the white and purple areas are each exactly half the area of the parallelogram.

Actually.... I really like what you did!  You worked it through carefully piece by piece and your reasoning is spot on.  But nesses argument could save a lot of time and understanding it will increase your intuition to see why this things should be "obvious".  It's not just that figure and those triangles.  It is any figure with any triangles.
